# Pass string or string array to a function in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell

I hope this is a simple question. I have a Powershell function that operates on all files in a given folder. There are times when I would like to have the function operate on a single folder and times when I would like it to operate on several folders, the paths of which are stored in an array. Is there a way to have one function be able to accept both a single element and an array?

```
Do-Stuff $aSingleFolder

Do-Stuff $anArrayofFolders
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also run the process section within the function.  It would look like this:

```
Function Do-Stuff {
    param(
        [Parameter( `
            Mandatory=$True, `
            Valuefrompipeline = $true)]
        [String]$Folders
    )
    begin {
        #Things to do only once, before processing
    } #End Begin

    Process {
         #What  you want to do with each item in $Folders
    } #End Process 

    end {
        #Things to do at the end of the function, after all processes are done
    }#End end
} #End Function Do-Stuff
```

Then when you call the Function. Do it like this

```
$Folders | Do-Stuff
```

Here is what will happen.  Everything in the `Begin` block will run first. Then, for each item in the `$Folders` variable, everything in the `Process` block will run.  After it completes that, it will run what is in the `End` block.  This way you can pipe as many folders as you want into your function.  This is really helpful if you want to add additional parameters to this function some day.

Comment: No problem, I definitely prefer doing functions like this, even if they are small. There have been a few lost hours rewriting a function to work on a larger scale.  Have a great week!

Comment: Note that, as declared using `[String]$Folders`, this function will _only_ work for multiple values passed through the pipeline. If you change the parameter declaration to `[string[]]$Folders`, then you can `foreach( $f in $Folders )` in the `process` block and it will work for `Do-Stuff <one folder>`, `Do-Stuff <multiple>, <folders>`, and `<multiple>, <folders> | Do-Stuff`. (Oh, and the backticks are unnecessary: open brackets and parenthesis count as continuations :)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that about the open brackets and such.  Thanks for the information on `[string[]]$folders`.  I look forward to using that at work :)  Have a great day!

Answer (score 7):

In Powershell, you can iterate over an array and a single element in a uniform manner:

```
function Do-Stuff($folders) {
    foreach($f in $folders) {
        //do something with $f
    }
}
```

Passing a single element will cause the foreach to be executed once with the given item.

```
Do-Stuff "folder"
Do-Stuff "folder1", "folder2",...
```

Comment: Okay, I feel dumb. : ) That was too easy! What I did was to change the function declaration from Do-Stuff ([string]$folder) to Do-Stuff ($folder) and it seems to be working. I had tried the foreach loop, but I got an error saying "...The given path's format is not supported" because the "given path" was multiple values from the array. I am now calling the function like this :
Do-Stuff $folder 
Do-Stuff $folderArray 

Why do I not have to include the [string] when declaring the function parameters?

Answer (score 0):

This works without cmd.exe and using files:

```
 function Invoke-PlinkCommandsIOS { 
     param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Host,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $Credential,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $Commands,
        [Switch] $ConnectOnceToAcceptHostKey = $false
    )
     $PlinkPath="$PSScriptRoot\plink.exe"
    $commands | & "$PSScriptRoot\plink.exe" -ssh -2 -l $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().username -pw "$($Credential.GetNetworkCredential().password)" $Host -batch
 }
```

Usage: dont forget your exit's and terminal length 0 or it will hang

```
PS C:\> $Command = "terminal lenght 0
>> show running-config
>> exit
>> "
>>
PS C:\> Invoke-PlinkCommandsIOS -Host ace-dc1 -Credential $cred -Commands $Command
```

....